# need some help with this parallel projection

Tags: education

[image]

Hi there,
I want anyone to analyse with  parallel projection cuz i got that and completely sure this is wrong i got it as this is how i see it https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouQ50.jpg (can't upload it here) 
my vision to the shape is a V letter and this thing like a triangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a 3D program and drawed the shape starting from the plane projections. Here are a few parallel projections. The leftmost is the isometric view. It seems to be same as in your question. Conclusion: No error.

[image]

Comment: Thank u very much xD the problem that i just tried to explain my point of view it to the prof and he didn't listen at all so i asked it here thank u <3 
what is the name of program ? it may help me :D

Comment: can u make this in 3D ? 
https://imgur.com/a/rX4C7
this was my answer ofc I now know it's wrong but i want to know how it will look like in 3D view

Comment: @user105393  The program = DesignSpark Mechanical, freeware, it's radically  crippled version of SpaceClaim, but still valuable. Your 2nd image has an internal contradiction, cannot be drawn. Your 1st image can have formal erros such as wrong line types. I do not know what are the rules there. Be warned: If you happen to be in a culture where "losing ones face" is fatal, do not  spit straight facts onto the professor.

Answer (score 1):

I like your little object. I am unsure what you believe the problem is. To me it looks (almost) correct.

Here I have separated the figure in two parts and moved them apart (note that you are missing one of the lines of the red figure in your drawing):

[image: Two separated parts]

If we move the parts to the correct position, we see that your drawing actually is correct:

[image: Overlayed parts]

What might look a little odd is the tile shared between the two parts, marked with an x here:

[image: Odd looking?]

That is just the downside with isometric drawing i guess. Sometimes it looks a little "impossible".

You can help the viewer to understand the figure a little better if you use varying stroke widths. Let the "inner" lines of the figure (where the angle of the faces change) be thinner than the "outer" lines (where the figure ends):

[image: Varying stroke widths]

Notice how this adds a little more depth to the drawing and defines the shapes more definitely.

Comment: thank you <3 my point of view was like this u can check it and tell me how this will looks like with 3D view
https://imgur.com/a/rX4C7